# ytdl-core not playing stream

Tags: javascript, discord.js, ytdl

I'm calling ytdl-core to stream a song into a discord bot. The bot connects to the channel but doesn't play any audio. I'm not getting any errors.

```
const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPjZmQAvk_8');
const resource = createAudioResource(stream, { inputType: StreamType.Arbitrary });
const player = createAudioPlayer();

player.play(resource);
connection.subscribe(player);

player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => connection.destroy());
```

This is what I believe the problem area is.

Comment: While answering at stackoverflow we expect you to provide us with the least possible debug information you get ☺️ I request you to attach a debug log of your websocket requests which can be obtained via adding a `debug` event listener on your client to the question so we may see if it's actually sending the stream bits. Thanks! ```client.on("debug", e => console.log(e));```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use a stack snippet for code that isn't runnable. Stack snippets are only meant for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that can be run on a browser. Please format your code using a [code block](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.